# How much Internet do I need to install CS:Go on Steam right now?

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive

I am planning to download CS:GO on my PC and I have some limited internet. How much data will be consumed to install it?

Answer (score 4):

The download alone uses 9.6 GB of traffic.

[image]

Extracted on your disk it will be about twice that amount (depending on your activity even more as custom maps, models, etc will be added to the size).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to the system requirements, CS:GO requires 15 GB of hard drive space. Based on this, the download size is in the realm of 15 GB.

You can check this more precisely by getting CS:GO, which is free, and trying to download it. Steam will inform you exactly how big the download is on the screen to select the install location.

[image: screenshot of the steam install window, which shows the disk space requirement]